# Why do rental car companies hand you two keys wired together?

Tags: car-rentals

Of late, every time I rent a car in the US, I'm handed two copies of the key, connected by an unbreakable wire cable. This makes a big, unwieldy, lump in my pocket. It also guarantees that, if I lose one, I lose both.

Why do the rental companies do this? Naively, I would expect them to want to keep one key in a safe place in case the renter screws up and loses a key.

My recent experiences of this have been with Alamo FWIW.

Comment: Last week, Enterprise cut the cable and re-did it on one key before handing it to me, with the explanation, "This way if you lose it we charge you $250 instead of $500."  :-)

Comment: I can confirm that it is the normal procedure, and I agree it seems pretty silly. I normally cut them right away (with an old nail scissor) to store them separated; nobody ever complained.

Comment: Huh.  I think the last few times, I've gotten *one* key wired to an awkward plastic fob.

Comment: Any other experiences with cutting the keys apart? It sure would be handy for each adult on a family trip having a key.

Comment: @WGroleau That is my first thought when handed those fobs - those things are **expensive** to replace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few reasons:

- There's actually less risk of losing both keys that way than
  splitting them up.
- It's easier to keep track of one set of keys rather then two.
- One-way rentals also cause a problem with the car
  and a key ending up in two different places.
- A key is not easily identifiable to a specific car so once it's detached, they might as well toss it.

Of course, this is a decision each agency will make on it's own.